# How to disable click in graph ChartJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, chart.js

I have the following code to render my chart in ChartJS:

```
public renderCanvas() {
this.canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

const gradient = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(10, 0, 120, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#429321');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#B4EC51');

const myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  options: { cutoutPercentage: 85, rotation: 2.72, circumference: 4, aspectRatio: 2.8, legend: { display: false }, onClick: null },
  data: {
    labels: ['clients.', 'no clients.'],
    datasets: [{ data: [this.segurosClients, this.prosperaClients], backgroundColor: [gradient, '#E3E7F3'], borderWidth: 1 }],
  },
});
```

but when I click, it opens this popup, I would like it to be disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the `onClick` property which you set to `null` doesn't do anything.

According to the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html#event-option), you can control which events the chart listens to  with the `events` property in the `options`. For example, if you want the chart to listen to all events, except `click`, try this:

```js
const myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  options: { 
      cutoutPercentage: 85, 
      rotation: 2.72, 
      circumference: 4, 
      aspectRatio: 2.8, 
      legend: { 
          display: false 
      },
      events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'],
  data: {
    labels: ['clients.', 'no clients.'],
    datasets: [{ data: [this.segurosClients, this.prosperaClients], backgroundColor: [gradient, '#E3E7F3'], borderWidth: 1 }],
  },
});
```